# ReactJS Why does this.refs not have updated class names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am using react-slick, and it has a carousel which has active slides that are shown to the user, which it signifies with slick-active. But when I call this.refs to get a view of my slides, which all have refs, then it doesn't have the slide-active in the class name.

I was wondering, what's the reason behind not having the updated class names?

I am calling this.refs in a onClick function.

Comment: this.refs.something points to a raw dom element, so there is no good reason unless it's not there at the time of you checking. You'll need to post code and possible a demo

Comment: How would you recommend getting the element after it's been updated?